# append() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to solve a for the real roots of my cubic equation where my coefficnets are actually arrays. I was able to find the roots but I am also trying to append all the real roots into a separtae array so I can use it for my other problems. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The error that comes out is:

> append() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given).

P.S: `gradU_all` is some array that I have previously defined.

MY CODE STARTS HERE: (ignore the weird format)

```
S=gradU_all

print S.shape

Wi=50

L=10

a=2*S**2*Wi**2

print a.shape

b=0

c=np.ones(N+2)

c*=L**2

c+=3

print c.shape

d=np.ones(N+2)

d*=-L**2

print d.shape


def Find_psi_real_roots():

    psi_real_roots=np.zeros(N+2)
    for i in range(N+2):
        #print 'for i:', i
        coeff= [a[i],0,103,-100]
        r=np.roots(coeff)
        real_valued = r.real[abs(r.imag)==0]
        psi_real_roots=np.append(real_valued[i])


Find_psi_real_roots()
```

Comment: [Try the docuemenation for `numpy.append()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Comment: i did! i just couldn't relate it to my issue :/

Comment: If you did, did you see that `numpy.append()` does not do what you think it does?

Comment: can you tell me a what good replacement would be then ?

Comment: From what you're doing, I really think you want `np.append(np, real_value[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

`np.append` is a generic function which helps to append to any numpy array-list object.

When you do `np.append(real_valued[i])` numpy doesn't really know what is needed because it does not know what to append `real_valued[i]` to. Hence, you need to tell it what to append the new root to.

```
psi_real_roots = np.append(psi_real_roots, real_valued[i])
```

Append the `real_value` to the array `psi_real_roots`